# Swift in iOS 6 Plus simulator: Custom UIView/ImageView cannot fill the top of the container view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, superview

I am trying to create a custom `UIView` that uses a `.xib` file, in which a `UIImageView` was dragged in the xib for displaying pictures. I have the following UIView subclass, however, the custom view/image view cannot fill the very top of the ViewController's superview, and I make sure the auto layout constraints are correct.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CustomMotionView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageContainerView: UIImageView!
    var imageArray: [UIImage] = []

    init(imageArray: [UIImage]) {
        super.init(frame: CGRectNull)
        xibSetup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibSetup()
    }

    private func xibSetup() {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(self.dynamicType), bundle: bundle)
        contentView = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleTopMargin]
        imageContainerView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleTopMargin]
        self.addSubview(contentView)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let p = (touch?.locationInView(self))!
        print("touches began!, point: \(p))") // this can provide hints for the boundaries of the CustomMotionView in its superview
    }
}
```

In the storyboard with a UIViewController, I dragged a `UIView` rectangle and assigned the `CustomMotionView` to its class. I set auto layout constraints to be: **0 (top), -20 (left), 0 (bottom), and -20 (right)**. The above `touchesBegan()` method suggests that the `CustomMotionView`'s layout is inflating fine in its container.

For the `UIImageView` dragged in the custom UIView's `xib` file, I make its auto layout constraints: (0,0,0,0). So it appears to me that the `UIImageView` in the xib cannot fill its superview's container (the UIViewController's view), I was wondering how to fix it. Please see the portrait view attached from my `iOS 6 Plus simulator portrait view` (but iOS 6 Plus simulator works fine with the landscape view mode; iOS 5S simulator works fine for **both** portrait and landscape view)

[image: white space in the top part of the container's view]

Comment: May I know what you used as the imageview's content mode? You could probably set different background color for the imageview and the uiview. That way we can know for sure whether the problem is the imageview not filling the uiview or the image not filling its imageview

Comment: @DicksonLeonard, that's a very good point! I am using `Scale To Fill` mode for the UIImageView. I am going to test it with different colors. Thanks